# Prestsashop one page checkout - Error: updateCartSummary is not defined

Tags: php, javascript, checkout, prestashop

This worked fine all last week, then i got a call from my client this morning saying that you that site doesn't complete its updates on the page, making it impossible for a customer to checkout.

To see the error, please add a product to cart, then try to create an account. The process updates, bu then stall when it tries to update the shipping. Users cannot select a method of shipping unless the page is refreshed.

There is an error in my error console, but it doesn't give me much guidance. Any ideas out there?
Error: updateCartSummary is not defined

site: www.stretchshapes.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it s resolve in version 1.4.7.3.
see the changelog : http://www.prestashop.com/en/developers-versions/changelog/1.4.7.3

> [-] FO : #PSCFI-4196 : bug fixed : Cart summary and minimum quantity (adding ajax check when updating product quantity)